# Draw attention to a database-centric question in a different SE community?

Tags: discussion

I have a [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/222502/does-the-objectid-in-an-oracle-geodatabase-table-have-a-primary-key-constraint) in the Geographic Information Systems SE community that is directly related to databases. Us non-DBAs are a bit confused about `primary key constraints`. (As insane as it might sound, `primary key constraints` aren't typically used in GIS databases.)

How can I draw the attention of knowledgeable DBA-SE community members to this question? It is my understanding that cross-listing posts is against the Stack Exchange rules. Otherwise, I'd just post the same question in DBA-SE.

Comment: You already have all the answers you need right there (including your own). What more are you expecting to achieve?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several general options:

- Mention your existing question in the target community's main chat room. For us, that would be [The Heap](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/179/the-heap--consultancy-). People may be willing to join the other site to answer there.
- Share a link to the question on social media or other platforms where database people are
- If the question gets no answers after a reasonable period of time, simply delete it and re-ask it on the other site (not applicable in the current case).
- Flag the question for a moderator to migrate (not applicable since the question has an open bounty, which has drawn attention, though you could wait until the bounty expires)
- Ask your question on the target site as well. This [can be OK](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu#comment181805_75012), so long as you *customize your question* for the target audience (i.e. not copy-paste).